# How to format the data of a file in Unix?

Tags: unix, dataformat

I have some data in this form (3 columns) stored in the variable `ABC`:

```
d1  d2 d3 
d4 d5 d6 
d7 d8 d9 
d10
```

and I would like to format it in this form (4 columns):

```
d1 d2 d3 d4 
d5 d6 d7 d8
d9 d10
```

I've tried something like this:

```
printf "%8.3e %8.3e %8.3e %8.3e\n" "${ABC}"
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: Not very clear what you mean, but if the format can be kept then `xargs -n4 < file` should suffice.

Comment: This worked fine.How can I choose your answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a file with a content like this:

```
d1 d2 d3
d4 d5 d6
d7 d8 d9
d10
```

and you want to convert it into

```
d1 d2 d3 d4
d5 d6 d7 d8
d9 d10
```

That is, convert it from 3 columns per line into 4.

For this you can use `xargs` like:

```
xargs -n 4 < file
```

Or, if the data is in a variable:

```
xargs -n 4 <<< "$variable"
```

From `man xargs`

> -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
>
> Use  at most max-args arguments per command line.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
$ xargs -n 4 < a
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10
```